# Why does min() works in Xcode, but not max ()?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am writing a C++ program using Xcode, and I need to find the max and min of two numbers. I decided to use the built-in `max` and `min` functions of C++.

When I do :

```
float result = min(x1,x2); // x1, x2 are floats
```

Xcode recognises `min` just fine.

But when I do:

```
float result = max(x1,x2); // x1, x2 are floats
```

Xcode complains with the error:

```
No matching function for call to 'max'
```

If I COMMAND + Click on either `max` or `min`, the Xcode quickly takes me to the function definitions, so clearly Xcode knows they are both there.

How do I get `max` to work ?

EDIT: I have tried calling std::max, but I get the same error.

Comment: try adding namespace to it, i.e. std::max instead of just calling max.

Comment: I tried std::max, but it makes no difference. Same error.

Comment: Can you paste the sample code, i mean how you are declaring x1, x2.

Comment: why not just use `fmax` and `fmin` ?

Comment: @John You should provide a complete example vs. just lines.  For instance I might ask "did you `#include <algorithm>`" *(I wouldn't have to ask if the example was a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))*.  For all we know you're *actually* using some library that defines a function min and not max :-/

Comment: @John Is this a real compiler error, or an IDE / code tag / parsing error?  If that error is *not* a compiler error, then that is a bug in your code tagging utility, not a C++ error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of error occur generally when your parameters that you are passing to min or max function is not of same type.

Make sure to check the parameter type of both parameters.

Comment: OMG! ur totally right man! I have no idea why those floats didn't look like floats to the compiler. Normally everything casts automagically! Weird!